# Pointer re-assignment, heap use after free

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm trying to write a simple function that swaps the nodes of a linked list (in which the values cannot be changed, just the nodes). Running into memory usage after free errors, and I can't pin it. I'm fairly certain the answer is quite straightforward and easy, I just can't see it right now.

```
void swapNodes(ListNode* a, ListNode *b){ //does not consider the root case
    auto * a1 = a->next;
    auto * a2 = a1->next;
    
    auto * b1 = b->next;
    auto * b2 = b1->next; // may be nullptr
    
    auto newA = std::make_shared<ListNode>(ListNode(b1->val, a2));
    auto newB = std::make_shared<ListNode>(ListNode(a1->val, b2));
    
    a->next = newA.get();
    b->next = newB.get();
}
```

I know it's missing a lot of checks, ignore that for now. Function receives two pointers (ideally references, but I'm restructuring still) to the nodes which need to be swapped.

Getting:

```
=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-use-after-free on address 0x603000000028 at pc 0x000000383abe bp 0x7ffe9bd980f0 sp 0x7ffe9bd980e8
READ of size 8 at 0x603000000028 thread T0
    #3 0x7f2499b8c82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x603000000028 is located 24 bytes inside of 32-byte region [0x603000000010,0x603000000030)
freed by thread T0 here:
    #7 0x7f2499b8c82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
previously allocated by thread T0 here:
    #10 0x7f2499b8c82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c067fff8000: fa fa fd fd fd[fd]fa fa fd fd fd fd fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32==ABORTING
```

Comment: Add a [mcve] as required please.

Comment: Swapping of nodes that require node allocations look suspicious. Moreover, how do you handle updates of predecessors of swapped nodes?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ : sorry I thought this problem was simple and classical enough not to require one. Thankfully I already have an answer though.

Comment: You’re not supposed to copy the values anywhere, including to new nodes.

Comment: @DanielLangr Just a problem requirement. Having read other comments I realized I really didn't need to allocate new objects, just change the pointers.

Comment: @Kronephon That you got an answer that solves your problem is irrelevant, regarding my point. This site isn't your personal helpdesk, but designed to be helpful for future readers who are researching about the same or similar problems. They cannot well decide if your case matches theirs w/o seeing a [mcve], and what exactly caused your problem. That's what constitutes a good, high quality and well received question here. So please take the time and improve your's if you're really interested in participating and contributing to SO. ...

Comment: @Kronephon ...  If you're looking at SO as a _Gimme a quick answer plz_ shoppe, you won't survive very long. Just saying.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @πάνταῥεῖ . I think you misinterpret my answer. I thought that the question was simple and apparent enough not to warrant testing locally. As you can see from my other comments in this page, I was def not approaching this in a just fix it perspective. I wanted to understand what was at fault and fix it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With

```
auto newA = std::make_shared<ListNode>(ListNode(b1->val, a2));
```

you create a new shared pointer object. This object is local inside the `swapNodes` function. Its life-time ends when the `swapNodes` function returns, and the object is destructed.

This destruction will lead to the memory allocated will be deleted, unless there's another shared pointer that shares the memory. And you code does *not* have such a shared pointer, which means that the assignment

```
a->next = newA.get();
```

will make `a->next` become invalid as soon as the `swapNodes` function returns.

The simple solution is to simply not use the shared pointers here.

Comment: Oh I was being silly I can just point to them, thanks.

As I understand your answer the problem is that I wouldn't have objects still pointing to the shared pointers, but to their contents no? Hence when the scope of the function ends, the ref count is 0 and the object is destroyed no?

Answer (score 3):

First, you make two shared pointers, and assign to local variables:

```
    auto newA = std::make_shared<ListNode>(ListNode(b1->val, a2));
    auto newB = std::make_shared<ListNode>(ListNode(a1->val, b2));
```

Now you use `get()` to get the underlying unmanaged pointers:

```
    a->next = newA.get();
    b->next = newB.get();
```

Finally the function finishes, `newA` and `newB` go out of scope, and the allocated memory is deleted.

```
}
```

However, `a->next` and `b->next` are still pointing to the memory that was being managed by the deleted `std::shared_ptr`, so you get your "use after free" error.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Although the problem is solved as I did not need to allocate anything after all, I'm curious. Is there any way, without using new, to keep the object alive in this situation? I suppose I would have had to return it by value and have the caller do the memory management...